# OWA Timeouts on Exchange 2013

Tags: outlook-web-access

Users using OWA are logged off after about fifteen minutes of inactivity.
There is no 'This is a public computer' tickbox.
running Get=OrganizationConfig in Powershell shows me

ActivityBasedAuthenticationTimeout Enabled - True
ActivityBasedAuthenticationInterval - 06:00:00

I'm not sure how to proceed in stopping this automatic logout after fifteen minutes. Are there any further suggestions or steps to follow?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help:

1. open regedit
2. go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSExchange
   WEB\OWA
3. there you should see two values TrustedClientTimeout and PublicClientTimeout
4. The default timeout for trusted clients is 24 hours; the default timeout for public clients is 15 minutes
5. check if you can change the values there

see if this help.

Comment: That path doesn't seem to exist. There is MXEchange OWA, but those keys are not inside.